# Django - Display the SQL for a create()?

Tags: django

I'm creating objects, ala `Book.objects.create(author=foo, ...)`, in a loop. Sometimes the `create()` raises an exception.

How can I view the SQL for the `create()` statement that failed?

The twist: The objects are created in a script that is not part of a request, thus middleware and the Django Debug Toolbar won't help me. I know about `django.db.connections`, but that only seems to return SQL statements which were successfully executed.

**UPDATE (Feb '14):** I never found an answer to this. Sorry.

Comment: Are you able to view log of your sql server?
i.e: tail -f /var/log/postgresql.log or similar

Comment: Yes, but /var/log/mysqld.log doesn't contain anything useful.

Comment: +1 I've always wondered if there's an easy way to get the raw SQL like `QuerySet.query` for methods that don't return a QS - although it still wouldn't help you if the SQL failed as you'd have an exception instead. Hmmm

Comment: @second - An `IntegrityError`, and the exception object only has `args` and `message` attributes.

Comment: why don't you catch exception in view and log parameters that you are sending to create function ?

Comment: +1 I would like to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails, i guess you could crack open the source, drop in some

```
try:
    ...
except IntegriyError:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

at various places in your stacktrace until you find somewhere with some sql